# List of browser as the are listed in IIS logs

Tags: iis, logging, browser, user-agent

Greetings,

I am looking for a list of browser entries as they are listed in an IIS log to help identify the different versions of browsers which visit our sites.  Perhaps there isn't a list but an algorithm which should be used to identify different browsers and their versions.

Please note that I am not looking for a log analyzer, but the different values I can expect for browser version in a log.  If their isn't a list of these, is there an algorithm I can follow to determine what the browser is and it's version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you're looking for is called the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).  Whenever you're dealing with these, it is helpful to remember that it can be changed by the end user and therefore shouldn't be completely trusted.  With that said, here are some good resources:

- [Common User Agents](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/CommonUserAgents.asp)
- A [big list](http://www.user-agents.org/) of less common user agent strings
- A user agent [analyzer](http://user-agent-string.info/)

Comment: Thank you Kevin.  I had figured out the User Agent term, but not the references.  The links are great, giving me just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a paid one then [here is one](http://www.weblogexpert.com/info/IISLogs.htm) for you. And Steve lists from free and open source iis log analyzers [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2007/09/04/log-analsyis-software-for-iis.aspx).

Edit: Check this [link out from MS Technet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bea506fd-38bc-4850-a4fb-e3a0379d321f.mspx?mfr=true) which has all the details about log files. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I am not looking for log analyzers, but the different entries to be expected in the logs for browser type.